# count number of tweets for a specific hashtag in real time

Tags: php, c++, twitter, web, go

how can you count the count number of tweets for a specific hashtag on twitter? is there a way to avoid php and creating twitter app on the twitter developer site?

i might want to use go or c++ instead of php.

Thanks,
Geri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to count Tweets in real-time, you will need to use the [Twitter Streaming APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public), in particular the [`statuses/filter`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter) endpoint. Using the `track` parameter with the hashtag you are interested in, you will receive matching Tweets in real-time.

In order to get started, you will need to create credentials for your Twitter app on https://apps.twitter.com/, then consume the API from your favorite language. The fastest way is to use an existing library which will handle the authentication and the connection to the Twitter API for you.

If you want to use Go, I definitely recommend [twittergo](https://github.com/kurrik/twittergo) by [@kurrik](https://twitter.com/kurrik) which supports the Streaming APIs. For other languages, you can take a look at this page on [Twitter Libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries).

Comment: Hi Romain, thanks for the short overview. how can i make sure i get all the tweets in real-time, in case if a lot of people tweet at the same time? from what i saw, you can only read 100 tweets at a time, the tweets have a data-tweet-id and data-time ... will that mean i need to read 100 tweets and always check which tweet i already read before?

Comment: @Gerald Using Streaming APIs, there is no rate limiting. It's with the REST API with an endpoint like `search/tweets` that you can indeed get 100 Tweets at a time. With Streaming APIs, like `statuses/filter` I mentioned, you keep one standing HTTP connection, and Tweets come in in real-time. The only limitation is that you can get up to about 1% of the firehose, but since there are more than 500 million Tweets a day on Twitter, it means you can get 5 million Tweets a day using the Streaming APIs! If the hashtag you track accounts for 1% or less of all Tweets, you will get all the results.

Comment: what happens if i read the first 100 tweets...do stuff to analyze them, in the meantime there are 300 tweets created...where is the start point to read the next 100 tweets? why is this limitation?

Comment: @Gerald I think you are still referring to the REST API, for which `since_id` and `max_id` are the way to paginate through the results of `search/tweets` for instance. That being said, for your use case of counting Tweets, I would still advise on using my initial recommendation with `statuses/filter` on the Streaming APIs. Not only it will be real-time, you will have nothing to do to handle pagination as Tweets will come in as they are posted.

Comment: thanks for the info. does it mean i cannot count tweets from the past using the Streaming API?

Comment: @Gerald That is correct. Streaming APIs is from this very moment on, in real-time, so if you want to count Tweets for an event or a TV show for instance, the way to go is to start streaming before the beginning. On the other hand, the REST API lets you search into the past (roughly a week) and perform actions on Twitter.

Comment: would it make sense if Twitter provides a uniform interface for both?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use tweepy a python API to access twitter APIS . But first you should have twitter streaming API access for that you should have an account at apps.twitter.com

Answer (score 1):

You will always need to create an app on the Twitter Developer portal https://apps.twitter.com/ as this is where you get to manage your API OAuth keys. As Romain says, the best option here would be to use the Streaming API.